# What purpose does a question serve that does not explain the problem clearly and is answered by the OP

Tags: discussion, specific-question, link-only-answers, specific-answer

I'm referring to the following question:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533362/why-doesnt-this-sed-line-work

The question appears more like a XY problem.  It reads:

> I am trying to remove everything that is MATCHED by the regex `;.*?$`
>   from a lot of files.
>
> The sed command I'm trying is:
>
> ```
> sed -i -e 's/;.*?$//g' files/*
> ```
>
> However, it does nothing.
>
> Any ideas how to get this working?

Despite getting an answer (which is apparently incorrect, though, as the question is not clear and subject to one's interpretation), and even after being asked for clarification in comments, the OP chooses to stay mum.  Instead, goes ahead and posts an answer:

> I want to delete this question, but it won't let me.
>
> `-e` is the wrong param. `-E` matches it.
>
> ---
>
> Details here:
>
> [Why doesn't this simple RegEx work with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344049/why-doesnt-this-simple-regex-work-with-sed?rq=1)

To me, such questions add little value to the site.  Incomprehensible post and link-only answer.

What should be done in such cases?  Or am I wrong in my interpretation of the post and it is, indeed, a high quality post as per SO standards?

---

UPDATE: The OP had, incorrectly, voted to close the post as a duplicate of the post referenced in the answer and it soon gathered enough votes to be closed as duplicate.  However, it has been deleted now.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of the question the OP linked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Unfortunately it's an example of a very poorly written question.  I doubt if it would help any future visitor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not a duplicate either -- I'm not sure how it managed to collect duplicate votes (perhaps because the OP initiated it).  To close it as duplicate is grossly misleading as it would imply that the `sed` supports non-greedy matches when using extended RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user at your reputation level, if the question cannot be salvaged, then downvote, vote to close, go into chat and get other people with vote to close privilege to vote on this question. The worst the question, the more eager people are going to vote to close. If you're lucky you might catch the eye of a moderator and get the question immediately closed. Once, it is closed, vote to delete. The case at hand here was closed as duplicate. Some duplicates are worth keeping around, but not all of them. Again, chat can be helpful for getting help deleting bad posts.

Someone who cannot vote to close but who can flag should flag and do the rest mentioned above. They can't do anything directly about deletion but if it is an absolute stinker, I guess they can flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was closed as a duplicate.  The OP chose to mark it (incorrectly) as a duplicate.  I'd say that it's only misleading to have such questions closed as dups.  Such questions ought to be purged.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda cut my answer short there. I've not been using my deletion powers that much myself so I tend to forget them. Oops... The specific question at hand is indeed a bad duplicate. I believe at your rep level you can vote to delete immediately.

Comment: It already has my (lone) delete vote.

Comment: [Robert Harvey](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) obliged and the post has now been deleted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the problem.  I understand the original question.  Frankly, I think it's quite a good question, even though it's written unclearly.  The answer isn't anywhere near detailed enough though - the correct answer varies according to which flavour of Unix you have.

Honestly, I would probably edit the question to make it clearer, but deleting it seems wrong.  I guess if I want an answer to this, I'll have to post a duplicate :-)

Moreover, I get really annoyed with people who downvote or VTC questions simply because what the OP is asking is outside their own personal area of expertise.  If all you have is a hammer, don't ban things that aren't nails - someone else might have a screwdriver.

Comment: I totally agree. Maybe it's just me but it seems that question could help a future person who was stuck not realizing they were mistakenly using `-e` rather than `-E`. It isn't the clearest of questions/answers but as someone who tends to get stuck on little details it seems helpful. I think sometimes SO as a whole forgets what it's like to be a noob.

Comment: If someone else *did* have the problem of mistakenly using `-e` instead of `-E`, then a) that is most likely a typo that should be closed as not reproducible; b) *how would someone find* the question? Especially given that there are countless problems that one might be trying to solve where `sed -E` is appropriate, and only one that looks like the one OP had?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry, I have no idea.  This was eight years ago, and I literally have no memory of ever having seen or answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm relatively new to SO, but I'm thinking right now, why complain?

On smaller forums, this is a big problem, but on a huge community such as those on StackExchange, questions are asked very quickly.

I would just flag/down vote (if I could) the post and move on, you don't need to kill yourself over a single little question. I know there are hundreds, if not thousands of horrible questions, but you don't need to bother with them, no one required you to do so.

In any case, someone will come along and down vote the question, just switch over it the higher voted questions and you get rid of the low quality ones.

So I'll end by saying that you should just flag or down vote and move on, and no, you are not wrong about that being a low quality question, but there is little you can do about it. Noobs are noobs, just stick with the pros.

Comment: It's too bad it's not just this one little question, otherwise, I'd agree with you.  Rather, it's death by a thousand little cuts.