# Reviewing First answer when OP answered own question saying that the problem was "elsewhere in the code"

Tags: discussion

I want to know how to properly perform a "First answer review" on this answer:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71134622/code-with-the-same-js-logic-doesnt-work-why/71149275#71149275*

As my question title says, OP answered their own question saying that the problem was "in another part of the code"

Is this the accepted way of handling this? Or would it be better if the user had closed their question instead?

I searched the meta and couldn't find anything that quite fits this scenario, although I have certainly seen this pattern on Stack Overflow before.

I found *[What purpose does a question serve that does not explain the problem clearly and is answered by the OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253967/what-purpose-does-a-question-serve-that-does-not-explain-the-problem-clearly-and)*, but it's not the same. The OP's answer is clear; it's just that the answer seems to invalidate the question.

Comment: *"Or would it be better if the user had closed their question instead?"* ... that's the correct approach. When the issue was somewhere else, then the question is, as it currently is, not reproducible and there is a close/flag reason for that.

Comment: @Tom Makes sense. Now as an answer reviewer, should I leave a custom comment suggesting this? The answer is not unclear, nor does it need supporting information.

Comment: Well, I won't say you _should_, because comments can result in harsh answers from OP when they don't accept/like your comment, but you _could_ if want to. You can also flag the question.

Comment: the reivew system, needs reviewing and optimizing again and again.

Comment: @Willow In this case, trying to convey to the OP that they should close their question after already answering it sounds... not worthwhile. The community should close this. I also think that even the most amiable user would be confused by those comments getting added _after_ they've already answered their question themselves, so I'd refrain from those for that reason too.

Comment: @zcoop98 that makes sense and I think is aligned with Jack's answer. My action on answer review shouldn't ask the user to close their own question, but rather just let them know I've flagged it to be closed.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Vote to close the question (if you have 3000+ rep) or flag the question (if you have under 3000 rep) as "**Not reproducible** or caused by typos". (Which is what's happened to the question here.)

Then for the "First Answers" review, add a comment like "Glad you solved it, but this question won't help any future SO users, therefore I'm voting to close the question", and pick "Other action". Or just skip.

Comment: You didn't mention it, but what about also downvoting the question on the grounds that it was _"not useful"_? Or is that just being unnecessarily hostile to a new user?

Comment: @skomisa Everyone has their own subjective approach to when to downvote, of course. But for me personally, I don't usually downvote a new user's question that I've already flagged to close (and is certain to *be* closed) unless it's pretty egregiously spammy, rude, or obviously just demanding code. I feel like if they appear to have made a good faith attempt, closing the question (and perhaps offering some advice in a comment) is enough.

Comment: I tried going to the question, but it has now been deleted and have no context. But going by what I've seen as question, with one answer (the OP), both being valid and well written, why close it?

Comment: Because, @RobMac, the question was off topic for SO, on account of not presenting a reproducible (from the contents of the question) issue.

Comment: That feel when you find something on stack overflow that is useful to you that was closed because it's not useful for future visitors, the irony

Comment: @Rainb When the answer is "the problem was in another part of the code" and was found by the Asker, that's not really useful to *anyone*, the Asker included.